# Multiple HTML Tables on One Page with Text

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have a webpage where there are multiple (4) HTML tables all inside of 1 div (that stretches basically the entire page and is there only to tell the tables how far down the page to begin) with headers that should appear just above each table. I built this site a couple years ago and everything worked fine until a recent Chrome update and now it seems the HTML tables and text like to jump all over the place.

Any suggestions on a better way to do this? I read somewhere else a suggestion of placing these tables inside of a larger table (which works) but I use CSS coloring to shade alternate rows different colors so it shades the entire page when I do it this way.

Here's an example of my code:

```
<div>

Title Above Table:
<br><br>
<table>
<tr><td>
table data
</td></tr>
</table>
<br><br>
Second Title Above Table:
<br><br>
<table>
<tr><td>
table data
</td></tr>
</table>
<br><br>

</div>
```

Also here is the actual site: http://mcgreeit.com/TourneyTime/leaderboard-elite8.php

If you press refresh a couple times you should see the text move around the tables and sometimes different tables even jump ahead of each other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML doesn't validate. Before you continue, try to debug the errors reported by the W3C Markup Validation Service at http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmcgreeit.com%2FTourneyTime%2Fleaderboard-elite8.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0